# Times Series - White Noise

Tags: time-series

If $X_t$ is a white noise time series, does it necessarily follow that $-X_t$ is also a white noise time series?

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $Y_1, Y_2, ...$ is a (weak) white noise process $WN(\mu,\sigma^2 )$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ if

1. $\mathbb{E}[Y_i] = \mu, \forall i$
2. $Var(Y_i) =\sigma^2, \forall i$
3. $Cov(Y_i,Y_j) = 0, \forall i\neq j$

Clearly if we would consider the sequence $-Y_1,-Y_2,...$, it would still be a white noise process, however with a different mean $\mu* = -\mu$.
The negative process would be $WN(-\mu,\sigma^2 )$

Comment: The question was whether $-X_t$ is white noise, not whether it is white noise with the same mean than $X_t$. I would answer that $-X_t$ is also white noise, albeit perhaps  with a different mean.

Comment: Indeed correct. My mistake.